# My script doesn't run when external script file is loaded on local drive

Tags: javascript

I'm making a simple tool - a HTML file on local drive that's opened via `file:///`. I need to link a script into it:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="file:///C:/.../externam.js">
 <script type="text/javascript">
  alert("Main script!");
 </script>
```

But the alert never launches (no script does). I tried different scripts. There are no errors in console.

Is this normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close your other `script` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///C:/.../externam.js"></script> 
                                                                   ^^^^
```

Comment: @TomášZato -- It's the little things in life :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to close your script tag when including an external script::

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///C:/.../externam.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  alert("Main script!");
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't closed the script tag!

replace your code by:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///C:/.../externam.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  alert("Main script!");
 </script>
```